# Input box opens if one cell change and another is blank

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following script that adds the techs id to COLUMN J when the status is changed to "COMPLETED"

However I want the input box to open if the target cell (COMPLETED_COLUMN_NUMBER) is empty

```
function onEdit(e) {
  COMPLETED(e);
}

SHEET_TO_WORK_ON = 'Scoresby'; // Please enter the name of your sheet here
STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER = 4;    // Enter the number of the column with the statuses here
LABOUR_COLUMN_NUMBER = 7;   // Enter the number of the column with the total amount charged here
COMPLETED_COLUMN_NUMBER = 10   // Enter the number of the column with the inspection 


function COMPLETED(e){
  let range = e.range,
      sheet1 = range.getSheet();

  if (sheet1.getName() == SHEET_TO_WORK_ON && range.columnStart == STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER && range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 'Completed'){
      range.offset(0,COMPLETED_COLUMN_NUMBER - STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER).setValue(Browser.inputBox('Tech ', 'Fill in the ID for the to who inspected the repair', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL))
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question from your explanation. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike I have added and example of when I would like to happen automatically

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I have made the question more basic. I want it to only open the input box if the target cell is empty

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from your updated question and your script. This is due to both my poor English skill and my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive both my poor English skill and my poor skill. I think that I have to study more.

Comment: Hi there @AndyJames! I don't understand what is preventing you from checking if the target cell is empty within your code. If you already have the `Range` object after calling the [`offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) method, then you could use [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) to check if it holds an empty string (empty cell). Would that be a valid solution for you?

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron. I am very new to app.script or any coding for that matter and can not work out how to incorporate it into my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to upgrade your code so it opens the input dialogue only if the target cell is empty. If my understanding of the scenario is correct, then there is one minor modification that you can script to upgrade your project. You only have to take the `Range` object in the script and use the [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) method to check if it is empty. In the following example I created the variable `targetCellData` to save the cell content. Then, if the cell is empty (meaning the content equals to `''`) the code runs the input dialogue.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  COMPLETED(e);
}

SHEET_TO_WORK_ON = 'Scoresby';
STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER = 4;
LABOUR_COLUMN_NUMBER = 7;
COMPLETED_COLUMN_NUMBER = 10;

function COMPLETED(e) {
  let range = e.range,
    sheet1 = range.getSheet();

  if (sheet1.getName() == SHEET_TO_WORK_ON && range.columnStart ==
    STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER && range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 'Completed') {
    var targetCellData = range.offset(0, COMPLETED_COLUMN_NUMBER -
      STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER).getValue();

    if (targetCellData == '') {
      range.offset(0, COMPLETED_COLUMN_NUMBER - STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER).setValue(
        Browser.inputBox('Tech ',
          'Fill in the ID for the to who inspected the repair', Browser
          .Buttons.OK_CANCEL));
    }
  }
}
```

Please test this approach and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron. it is now working exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks for your help